# How does a Java thread behave when a method is accessed externally?

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following thread:

```
public class MyThread {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // do something forever
        }
    }
}
```

Then I instantiate the thread as follows:

```
MyThread thread = new MyThread();
```

What happens if I now call

```
thread.performSomeFunction()
```

Specifically, how does performSomeFunction interact with the infinite loop above?  Does it have to wait for the loop to sleep?  Or can they both run "concurrently"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `thread.performSomeFunction()` is called from another thread, it does not have to contend with the infinite loop that is being run in the `run()` method.  In this case, your `MyThread` instance is treated like another object that can have methods called on it.

Note that your infinite loop will not start until you start your `thread` instance.

You can test this out by putting the following line in both the `run()` method and your `perfomrSomeFunction()` method:

```
System.out.println("in [METHOD NAME]: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

and replace the `[METHOD NAME]` with the actual method name.